# TextView not hiding

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` i want to hide, quite easy I thought. But this is giving me a headache. The www did as well not have an answer.

I "fixed" the problem by calling `timer.setText("");`, to the user it looks like it dissapred. I have many Views, so I have this `int visibility = warmup ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE;` all the other controls hide perfect, except this one. I hard coded it as well to `View.GONE`, with the same result.

```java
TextView timer = findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
timer.setVisibility(visibility);
timer.setText("");
```

If I call `.setVisibility()` on a view, I excpect the **normal** behaviour.

Comment: Question, is your `timerTextView` id correct and are you on the same view with it? You can try to Clean/Build your project in case something odd has hapened.

Comment: actually thats not the case, it works, you need to check your other code, may be its  made visible somewhere else. or you are trying to hide it through background thread.

Comment: The Id is correct, otherwise the setText would not work. I will check my code, if it's made visible somewehere else

Comment: @ChristianBohli you can give a temporary background color to the textview and then test and verify your code, its just an illusion to you, problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I found an other ocurence in my code, handling this correct, solved the issue

Comment: sure, what ever floats your boat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually thats not the case,

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

it always works perfectly. You need to check your other code, may be its made visible somewhere else. or you are trying to hide it through background thread. you can give a temporary background color to the `TextView` and then test and verify your code, its just an illusion to you, problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) // This will hold the position and space but just hide the view.
timer.setVisibility(View.GONE) // This will not hold the position and space. It will disapear.
```

I guess you need to check what the `warmup` is. It should work if it works fine.

Otherwise, it'd be worth to apply `databinding`. And use that expression in the layout.

Like

```
visibility=""@{vm.hide ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

When `hide` which is the ViewModel's variable has the value of true. Then, all the views that is data bidden will work perfectly.